# Cassandra count query failing due to AssertionError

Tags: cassandra

I am trying out Cassandra for the first time and running it locally for simple session management db. [Cassandra-2.0.4, CQL3, datastax driver 2.0.0-rc2]

The following count query works fine when there is no data in the table:

```
select count(*) from session_data where app_name=? and account=? and last_access > ?
```

But after even a single row is inserted into the table, the query fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.ExtendedFilter$WithClauses.getExtraFilter(ExtendedFilter.java:258)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.filter(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1719)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getRangeSlice(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1674)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.PagedRangeCommand.executeLocally(PagedRangeCommand.java:111)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalRangeSliceRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1418)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1931)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is the schema I am using:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE session WITH replication= {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

CREATE TABLE session_data (
username text,
session_id text,
app_name text,
account text,
last_access timestamp,
created_on timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (username, session_id, app_name, account)
);

create index sessionIndex ON session_data (session_id);
create index sessionAppName ON session_data (app_name);
create index lastAccessIndex ON session_data (last_access);
```

I am wondering if there is something wrong in the table definition/indexes or the query itself. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're tripping over a bug in Cassandra.  Here is the assertion and related comments in the Cassandra sources:

```
/*
 * This method assumes the IndexExpression names are valid column names, which is not the
 * case with composites. This is ok for now however since:
 * 1) CompositeSearcher doesn't use it.
 * 2) We don't yet allow non-indexed range slice with filters in CQL3 (i.e. this will never be
 * called by CFS.filter() for composites).
 */
assert !(cfs.getComparator() instanceof CompositeType);
```

This code was modified between **cassandra-2.0.4** and **trunk** as part of ticket [CASSANDRA-5417](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5417), but it's not clear to me that the author was aware of this issue.  The assertion was removed, but the comment was not.  I would recommend submitting a bug report to the Cassandra project.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I submitted a bug report [CASSANDRA-6612](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6612).

Comment: In the meantime, would you know if there is another recent stable version which may not have this issue ? The download page lists: 2.0.4 and 1.2.13. But I don't know enough about Cassandra to understand the underlying differences between the two.

Comment: I tried your schema on Cassandra 1.2, and got `Bad Request: Cannot create index on PRIMARY KEY part` for `session_id` and `app_name`. It seems secondary indexes on primary key parts are an issue. Try creating a separate, single valued primary key (the value can be a concatenation of username+session_id+app_name_account, and its contents will be redundant with those fields.)

Comment: I ran into the same issue when I tried. I remember reading somewhere that 1.2 supports secondary indexes on composite key fields.. but maybe not. By single valued primary key, do you mean have an additional column to store concatenated value and then use this column as primary key ? Or is there a better way to achieve this in CQL ?

Comment: Thank you @AndyS. I was able to work around the problem by creating separate primary key with concatenated columns. I am still not clear on why I am not able to create secondary indexes on primary key columns, but I'll accept this answer as it gets me past that specific error.